# Images not release in memory

Tags: ios, image, memory-warning

I have table with Images cell. Images download from internet and save in local disk. Count = 200. Tableview show this images. When scroll content to bottom, comes message memory warning... Used memory 250 - 300 mb O_O!!! Links to images that do not keep.

```
NSString *cellID = @"cellId";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
...
NSString* imagePath = [arrayContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
[cell.imageView setImage:image];
```

Why hide images not release?

Comment: Use Instruments to know exactly at what point your app memory is increasing.

Comment: Allocations: VM ImageIO_PNG_Data 281 mb O_o!!! Why???

Comment: Want to know why ARC is not releasing UIImage object. You are using ARC right?

Comment: When you run the static analyzer does it give you any warnings?

Comment: **Guy Kogus**, many messages with `memory warning`, how to handle them and releasing images?

Comment: You need to put the code in @autoreleasepool{} block

Comment: **karthika**, @autoreleasepool{} not help...

Comment: Are you reusing UITableView cell's ? Please post your entire cellForRowAtIndexPath code. Also what size do the images have you are providing the cell's?

Comment: Images 320*640. Cells height 640. `NSString *cellID = @"cellId"; cellForRowAtIndexPath code look to top

Comment: Well you should use instruments and monitor the allocations/deallocations. You might be holding a reference to the cell or the UIImage somewhere that prohibits the release of the object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace this line

```
UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

with this and check once

```
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

Comment: Just added an edit that explains it. If it is approved, you will see it soon. In short, the first line code block never releases memory as ARC is probably turned off. The second code block returns an autoreleased UIImage, so there is no leak.

Comment: In case images on screens are loaded from Xib - is there a way to avoid non-releasing of VM ImageIO_PNG_Data ?

Comment: @Ganapathy thanx i was also getting the same warning. now its resolved. but i my application memory is still continously increase and after some time app crash. plz look my code and let me know what i m doing wrong. why memory not release. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29017579/receive-memory-warning-when-i-display-image-from-document-directory-during-scrol

Answer (score 0):

Well I used a custom `MSAsyncImageCell` class that replaces its image when reused by iOS. It loads the image from a URL asynchronously, displaying a "loading" image gracefully and release memory when reused for another image. If you want I can post the code here but the code is a bit long.

Here is the part of code that actually loads the image. I have images off web/caches so it is NSData.

```
- (BOOL)_loadImageWithData:(NSData *)imageData
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    // Just in case loading failed.

    if (image)
    {
        // Extra check - don't mix up.
        if ([[self.currentURL absoluteString] isEqualToString:[self.imageURL absoluteString]])
            self.asyncImageView.image = image;

        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```